# Train and deploy model using sparkling water

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, h2o

I want to train and deploy a h2o model using mlfow spark as mentioned in the diagram: https://res.infoq.com/presentations/mlflow-databricks/en/slides/sl21-1566324281761.jpg
I found 2 ways of training the model:
1. https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/h2o-sparkling-water-python.html
2. https://www.h2o.ai/blog/h2os-automl-in-spark

Using the first approach, I am able to train the H2o model but unable to deploy using mlflow spark as it expects a spark model.
When I try to use second approach, it throws below error during training while running sample example given in the link.
"pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`label`' given input columns:"

Can anyone help and let me know which approach should I use for training the model in sparkling water and deploy the same in spark.

Comment: provide your code & full error

Comment: Also, are you using Databricks? What are you deploying to? What do you mean it expects a Spark model? The Databricks example right at the top mentions creating a Databricks library which you can attach to the cluster with the h20 packages required, then you can run databricks jobs with the API with those same packages